# Can you trigger a shell script on `eb setenv`?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We currently run a migrations script as a `container_command`, which does not appear to run when changing an environment variable using `eb setenv`. Is there an AL1 way to run a post environment variable being set script?

Answer (score 0):

You could run the following from the terminal where eb is the path to the elasticbeanstalk script

cat .env | while read line ; do    /path/to/eb setenv $line  ; done